# How do I handle exceptions in a procedural language?

Tags: perl, exception

How do I do exception handling in a procedural language like C or Perl? (I know Perl also does OO.) What’s the best way to handle exception in procedural code in Perl?

Comment: Enough programming in Perl is *procedural programming*, but that doesn't make it a procedural *language*. It's a multi-paradigm language. It allows OO programming, but it also borrows from *functional* programming languages. The one thing I don't think it could do without a lot of work is *logical* programming (like Prolog). Where `C` is a procedural language, and the closest you can get is by practicing and enforcing Abstract Data Types methodology.

Comment: @Axeman, see the AI::Prolog distribution on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/~jjore/AI-Prolog/lib/AI/Prolog.pm

Answer (score 7):

In Perl 5 the exception handling is done using `eval` and `die`. You simply eval the body of code and if it dies, you can inspect `$@` for the error. It’s not exactly this easy if you want to do it properly, which is why the various try/catch modules exist. You might be interested in [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Try::Tiny) which has no dependencies and describes all the gotchas you have to deal with when using the naive eval exception handling. (Also see [this blog post](http://blog.woobling.org/2009/09/trytiny.html) by Try::Tiny’s author.)

Comment: "eval" has performance penalties that may make it prohibitively expensive for large scale systems.

Comment: @DVK, are you talking about string eval or block eval?  The issues with string eval are well known, but exception handling with eval typically uses block eval.  If you are saying that there are performance issues with block eval, can you provide a source or demonstration of the issue?

Comment: @zoul, I think you have an error: `'with eval' => &with_eval` needs a `\` before the sub name.  On my perl 5.8 system, two layers of eval has a 44% penalty over no eval, and one layer gives a 24% penalty.  However, I think this may be an unfair benchmark.  Wrapping a database query or file access in an eval is not going to have this sort of overhead, since those operations are unlikely to be CPU bound. I think the lesson to be learned here is that you can go too far with your evals.  Wrap reasonable sized chunks of code and you won't spend all your time creating and tearing down eval contexts.

Comment: @daotoad: Oh my. The backslash makes quite a difference, doesn’t it? :) Thank you, fixed. Now the performance difference is around 1/3, but as you already wrote, this does not have to mean much.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example of how I do exceptions in Perl (without using one of the Try modules):

```
use Carp;
use English qw( -no_match_vars );

do_something_needing_rollback_if_failed();
eval {
    do_something_dangerous();
} or do {
   # Exception was thrown by dangerous method
   # Save the error:
   my $error = $EVAL_ERROR;

   # Try to rollback
   eval { rollback(); }
     or do { confess qq{Couldn't rollback: $EVAL_ERROR. Original error $error}; }

   # Let's rethrow:
   confess qq{Rolled back! Error was $error};
}
```

One of the more annoying parts of Perl exception handling is it uses a single variable to store any exception error, and it can get accidentally overwritten, so some defensive coding is required.

Answer (score 1):

It rather depends what you mean by 'exception handling'.

Some OS have exception mechanisms - see [Windows exception handling routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6d85y967(VS.80).aspx) or [Linux signal handlers](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3985) ( some of which are exceptions ).

If you mean the idiom in user code to signal an error and unwind the stack cleaning up any allocated objects, then C code doesn't call destructors on allocated objects when the stack is unwound ( it just reclaims the memory ), so it's normal in C for functions to return a status value, and for the calling code to do any clean up required before returning.

I don't know Perl well, but Googling for "Perl exception handling" indicates it has both built in mechanisms equivalent to try/catch and modules which give "OO style" exception handling.

Answer (score 1):

In C there was setjmp and longjump; essentially, setjmp() saves the current context in the stack, and longjmp() can unwind its way back to the point saved by setjmp(). The wikipedia entry on those fills in the details nicely.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, as usual, there is more than one way to do it. However the community of developers have as a whole settled on the correct way to do most things.

I'm becoming a fan of [Exception::Base](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Exception-Base) myself.

If you want a lighter implementation then just use Carp.

You trap exceptions using an `eval { ... }; if ($@) { ... }` construct.

With Exception::Base it offers a way to abstract out the `if ($@) { ... }` construct for you. You will still need to use `eval { ... }` though.

Answer (score 0):

The traditional approach is to... well... not to :)

Generally, people just check the status after attempting something, and if something went wrong, they clean up and return an error code, rather than continuing.  This error checking and returning propagates back down the function call stack until it gets back to somewhere high-level in your program, where you care to inform the user instead of just returning more errors:

```
int try_it() {
  if (!do_something(...)) {
     return TRYIT_FAILURE;
  }
}

void my_gui() {
  rc = try_it()
  if (rc == TRYIT_FAILURE) {
    message_box("failed when trying it.", MB_ABORT|MB_RETRY);
  }
  ...
}
```

You can also do this in a big function, using nested ifs, if you want something like a try...except construct:

```
if (stage1()) {
   if (stage2()) {
       if(stage3()) {
           printf("success!\n");
       } else {
           // error handling for stage 3
       }
   } else {
       // error handling for stage 2
   }
} else { 
   // error handling for stage 1
}
```

And you can do the same with gotos if you're a bit mad.

However, you can do actual exceptions, at least in C.  C has two standard library calls for this sort of thing: setjmp and longjmp.  With these, you can jump back through several function calls to a predetermined place, where you know the exception (jump) happened.  See [Setjmp.h#exception_handling on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setjmp.h#Exception_handling) for more on that.

It seems Perl does have a way of doing this, though it looks far from intuitive to me.  Then again, I don't code in Perl :)

[Perl FAQ Q4.8](http://unlser1.unl.csi.cuny.edu/faqs/perl-faq/Q4.8.html)

Comment: -1 Perl developers do most certainly use exceptions. I would argue they are more important in a dynamic language like perl than in a language like java or C++;