# What is the best way to handle exceptions in Perl?

Tags: perl, exception, error-handling, eval

I've noticed that Exception.pm and Error.pm don't seem to be extensively used in the Perl community.  Is that due to the large footprint of `eval` for exception handling?

Also Perl programs appear to have a much more lenient policy regarding exception handling in general.  Is there a compelling reason for this?

In any event what would be the best method for exception handling in Perl?

Comment: dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503189/is-object-oriented-exception-handling-in-perl-worth-it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165161/whats-broken-about-exceptions-in-perl
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439966/do-you-use-an-exception-class-in-your-perl-programs-why-or-why-not
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1426501/how-do-i-handle-exceptions-in-a-procedural-language -- do we really need another post about Perl exception handling?

Comment: See my answer in [Is Try::Tiny still recommended for exception handling in Perl 5.14 or later?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10374265/2766176)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The consensus of the Perl community seems to be that [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Try::Tiny) is the preferred way of doing exception handling. The "lenient policy" you refer to is probably due to a combination of:

- Perl not being a fully object-oriented language. (e.g. in contrast to Java where
  you can't avoid dealing with exceptions.)
- The background of many Perl developers. (Languages like C<sup>1</sup> and shell don't have
  exception mechanisms.)
- The kind of tasks people tend to use Perl for. (Small scripts for text munging and
  report generation where exception handling isn't needed.)
- Perl not having a (good) built-in exception mechanism.

Note that the last item means that you'll see a lot of code like this:

```
eval { something() };
if ($@) {
    warn "Oh no! [$@]\n";
}
```

That's exception handling even though it doesn't use try/catch syntax. It's fragile, though, and will break in a number of subtle edge cases that most people don't think about. Try::Tiny and the other exception handling modules on CPAN were written to make it easier to get right.

<sub>1. C does have `setjmp()` and `longjmp()`, which can be used for a very crude form of exception handling.</sub>

Comment: And just to clear up a common misconception which the original poster might or might not suffer from: `eval BLOCK` is *not* `eval STRING` and doesn't compile code at runtime. It's just an exception-handling method -- `try` with a funny name and slightly funny semantics.

Comment: If we consider `setjmp`+`longjmp` an exception handling mechanism in C (however crude), then shell also has one: `trap`+`kill` (although it seems even cruder).

Comment: For your information, there is now a full try-catch implementation in perl with the module [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try)

Answer (score 8):

Never test $@ as is, because it is a global variable, so even the test itself can change it.

General eval-template:

```
my $result;

eval {
    $result= something();
    # ...
    1;  # ok
} or do {
    my $eval_error= $@ || "error";
    # ...
    die $eval_error;
};  # needs a semicolon
```

In practice that is the lightest way. It still leaves a tiny room for funny $@ behaviour, but nothing that really concerned me enough.

Answer (score 2):

As it has been mentioned you can use the traditional way with [eval](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlfunc#eval-EXPR), but if you want to use more elaborate exception trapping, including with exception objects, then I recommend using the try-catch-finally blocks.
There are quite a few perl modules that provide it such as [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try) and [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try), but [Syntax::Keyword::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Syntax::Keyword::Try) does not provide exception variable assignment or exception class catch like

```
  try
  {
    # something
  }
  catch( Exception $e )
  {
    # catch this in $e
  }
```

Full disclosure: I am the developer of [Nice::Try](https://metacpan.org/pod/Nice::Try)

Comment: Nice::Try is excellent, it has everything I always wanted for handling exceptions in Perl.