# Perl - copy variables value out of BEGIN block

Tags: perl, copy, block

I have a simple script:

```
our $height = 40;
our $width = 40;

BEGIN {
    GetOptions( 'help' => \$help,           
                'x=i' => \$width,
                'y=i' => \$height) or die "No args.";


    if($help) { 
        print "Some help";   
        exit 0;
    }

    print $width."\n"; #it is 10 when call with script.pl -x 10 -y 10
    print $height."\n"; #it is 10 when call with script.pl -x 10 -y 10

    #some other code which check installed modules

    eval 'use Term::Size::Any qw( chars pixels )';
    if ( $@ ) {
        if ( $@ =~ /Cant locate (\S+)/ ) {
            warn "No modules";
            exit 2;
        }
    }


}

print $width."\n"; #but here is still 40 not 10
print $height."\n";#but here is still 40 not 10
```

I call this script with 2 parameters (x and y), for example: script.pl -x 10 -y 10. But the given values are not saved in variables $width and $height. I want change this variables by giving arguments. How can I copy given values or save them into `$width` and `$height`? Is it possible?

**EDITED** - I added some code to this example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `BEGIN` blocks are executed in the *compile phase*, as soon as possible (right after they're parsed) -- before the *run phase* even starts.  See this [in perlmod](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmod.html#BEGIN,-UNITCHECK,-CHECK,-INIT-and-END) and see [this "Effective Perler" article](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2011/03/know-the-phases-of-a-perl-programs-execution/). Also, the declaration part of `my $x = 1;` happens in the compile phase as well, but the assignment is done at runtime.

Thus the `$height` and `$weight` are declared, then your code to process the options runs in its `BEGIN` block, and once the interpreter gets to the run phase *then* the variables are assigned `40`, overwriting whatever had been assigned in that `BEGIN` block.

Thus a way around that is to *only declare* these variables, without assignment, before the `BEGIN` block, and assign that `40` after the `BEGIN` block if the variables are still undefined (I presume, as default values).

However, it is better not to process options, or do any such extensive work, in a `BEGIN` block.

Here are a couple of other ways to do what you need.

Loading the module during compilation is fine for your purpose, as long as you know at runtime whether it worked. So load it as you do, under `eval` in a `BEGIN` block, so that you can set a flag for later use (conditionally). This flag need be *declared* (without assignment) before that `BEGIN` block.

```
my $ok_Term_Size_Any;

BEGIN { 
    eval 'use Term::Size::Any qw(chars pixels)';
    $ok_Term_Size_Any = 1 unless $@;
};

# use the module or else, based on $ok_Term_Size_Any
```

The declaration happens at compile time, and being in `BEGIN` so does the assignment -- under the conditional `if not $@`. If that condition fails (the module couldn't be loaded) the assignment doesn't happen and the variable stays undefined. Thus it can be used as a flag in further processing.

Also: while the rest of the code isn't shown I can't imagine a need for `our`; use `my` instead.

---

***NOTE**   Please consult this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41094774/cannot-load-core-cwd-and-other-non-core-modules-at-runtime) for subtleties regarding the following approach*

Alternatively, load all "tricky" modules at runtime. Then there are no issues with parsing options, what can now be done normally at runtime as well, before or after those modules, as suitable.

The `use Module qw(LIST);` statement is exactly

```
BEGIN {
    require Module;
    Module->import(LIST);
};
```

See [use](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html). So to check for a module at runtime, before you'd use it, run and [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) that code

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

eval {
    require Module;
    Module->import( qw(fun1 fun2 ...) );
};
if ($@) {
    # Load an alternative module or set a flag or exit ...
};

# use the module or inform the user based on the flag
```

Instead of using `eval` (with the requisite error checking), one can use [Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~ether/Try-Tiny-0.27/lib/Try/Tiny.pm) but note that there are issues with that, too. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10364975/is-trytiny-still-recommended-for-exception-handling-in-perl-5-14-or-later), also for a discussion about the choice. The hard reasons for using a module instead of `eval`-and-`$@` have been [resolved in 5.14](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Exception-Handling).

---

Comment: Looks good, but I get an error stack trace if module is not installed. The idea is if module is not installed I want to show inform message that module is not installed and exit. But if I run a program with -h option I want to show a help message even if module is not installed. Is it possible?

Comment: In the first example, are you sure `$ok_Term_Size_Any` will be set after BEGIn block? I think it will have default value or error will be thrown because it is not initialized.

Comment: *"your code to process the options runs before the variables are assigned 40"* This doesn't explain why the `BEGIN` block is executed before `40` is assigned to the variable. The assignment precedes the `BEGIN` block and isn't in a `BEGIN` block itself?

Comment: @Borodin  I don't see how it doesn't explain it ...? The processing of options runs first (before the runtime-assignment), because it is in a `BEGIN` block, while the assignment to `40` happens in the run phase, which comes later.  The first sentence establishes this. Are you saying that the wording is unclear?

Comment: @allocer  I don't understand.  Try this  `my $ok_NoMod; BEGIN { eval 'use NoMod'; $ok_NoMod = 1 unless $@ };  if ($ok_NoMod) { say "Have NoMod" } else { say "No 'NoMod' }`.  Add warnings and strict.  It says `'No NoMod'` and if I use a module that I do have (instead of this "_NoMod_") then it says `'Have ...'`.  This is what you need, no?

Comment: @zdim: On the face of it, `use strict; my $var = 42; BEGIN { $var = 84 }; print $var;` should either die in the `BEGIN` block because there is no such variable, or print `84`. Neither of these happens, and you haven't explained why. I'm sorry, I know it's easy to overlook things that gave become "obvious", and your answer is otherwise a great one.

Comment: @Borodin Oh, I see what you mean.  I thought that the sentence after the code block was a good place to do it.  But, you are right, it should be explained upfront. I'll amend the first paragraph.

Comment: @zdim: That sentence doesn't address the phase when the *assignment* occurs, or that it is different from when the *declaration* happens. That concept is the core of the answer.

Comment: @Borodin  I edited, but will check again in a few minutes.  Apparently it is all too easy to mess up the business of what things are explained and when.  It wasn't done well at all -- when I looked it now.  It seemed just fine last night. Thank you.

Comment: @allocer  I see your second comment only now, for some reason.  If the module loaded fine (and so `$@` is empty) the flag is set -- the variable is assigned `1`.  If it didn't load (so `$@` has stuff) the flag isn't set -- it stays `undef`. So you can use it later as a flag, `if ($ok_Term_Size_Any) ...`.  So you can decide what messages to  print, etc.

Comment: Guys, thanks for help. It helped me with first example. Sorry for my stupid questions ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `BEGIN` clause is executed *before* normal code. When you declare `$height` and `$width`, you set them to 40 *after* you process the options.

Solution: process the options outside the `BEGIN` clause.

Comment: I know. But what if user has not installed modules (`eval...`) and I want to show help (-h) always? When I process option after begin block, I will get "No modules" message all the time. When I process option in begin block, when I pass -h otpion I'll get first "Some help" message instead of "No modules". Is it possible to copy values from begin block outside?

Comment: Why bother doing that in `BEGIN` either? If you really need custom help with module installs, then you can load modules using `require` at runtime.

Comment: use `require` instead of `use`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that declaration/definitions like `our $height = 40` etc. are executed in two phases. The *declaration* is performed at compilation time, while the *assignment* is done at run time. That means something like

```
my $x = 0;

BEGIN {
    $x = 1;
}

say $x;
```

will display `0`, because `$x` is *declared* at compile time and set to 1 at compile time because of the `BEGIN` block. But it is then set to zero at run time.

All you need to do it change the declaration/definition to just a declaration. That way there is no run-time modification of the assignment made by the `BEGIN` block

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

my $xx;

BEGIN {
    $xx = 1;
}

say $xx;
```

#### output

```
1
```

Note that there is no need for `our`. `my` is almost always preferable. And please don't use `BEGIN` blocks to execute significant chunks of code: they should be reserved for preparatory actions of comparable to loading the required modules before run time starts. No one expects a program to output help text if it won't compile, which is what you are trying to do.