# In Perl, how can I set $! before returning something from a function?

Tags: perl, return

Imagine I have this simple function

```
say_hi() || die "ERROR: sub say_hi had an issue: Details => $!\n";

sub say_hi{
   my ($name) = @_;
   return unless $name;
   print "Hi $name\n";
   return 1;
}
```

How can I set the content of **$!** in the sub so that it can be used after function returns. I'm trying to do something similar to what

```
open() || die "$!";
```

does. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`perldoc -v $!`:

> When referenced, `$!` retrieves the ***current value of the C "`errno`"
>               integer variable***. If `$!` is assigned a numerical value, that value
>               is stored in "errno". When referenced as a string, `$!` yields the
>               system error string corresponding to "`errno`".
>
> ... Assignment to `$!` is similarly ***ephemeral***. It
>               can be used immediately before invoking the "`die()`" operator, to
>               set the exit value, or to inspect the system error string
>               corresponding to error `n`, or to restore `$!` to a meaningful state. (*emphases mine*)

That explains why you can't do the obvious:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

say_hi() or die "ERROR: sub say_hi had an issue: Details => $!\n";

sub say_hi{
   my ($name) = @_;
   unless ($name) {
       $! = 'no name';
       return;
   }
   print "Hi $name\n";
   return 1;
}
```

That results in:

> `ERROR: sub say_hi had an issue: Details =>`

Consider using `eval`/`$@`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

eval { say_hi() } or die "ERROR: sub say_hi had an issue: Details => $@\n";

sub say_hi{
   my ($name) = @_;
   $name or die "no name\n";
   print "Hi $name\n";
   return 1;
}
```

See also "[Is Try::Tiny still recommended for exception handling in Perl 5.14 or later?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10364975/100754)"

If you follow brian's recommendation in this answer to that question, you can do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $r = say_hi();

$r->{success}
    or die sprintf "ERROR: sub say_hi had an issue: Details => %s\n", $r->{reason};

sub say_hi{
   my ($name) = @_;
   $name or return { success => 0, reason => 'Missing "name"' };
   print "Hi $name\n";
   return { success => 1 };
}
```

Or, you can use [Params::Validate](https://metacpan.org/pod/Params::Validate) or [Validate::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Validate::Tiny) etc.

Answer (score 3):

`$!` is a proxy for C's `errno`. The values `errno` can take are available as constants in [Errno](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Errno).

```
use Errno qw( EINVAL );

sub foo {
   my ($arg) = @_;
   if (!$arg) {
      $! = EINVAL;
      return 0;
   }

   ...

   return 1;
}

foo(...)
   or die($!);
```

This is rarely done, mostly because you are limited to error codes designed for system calls. It's far more common to throw exceptions or have a module-specific error variable (e.g. `$DBI::err`).