# How to handle exceptions in perl?

Tags: perl, clearcase

I'm trying to find the last access date of clearcase view,  perl script looks like below.

```
    @Property = `cleartool lsview -prop $viewtag ` ;

foreach $property (@Property)
    {
    $last_accessed = $property if ( $property =~ /^Last accessed / ); 
            # | cut  -b 15-24 | awk -F '-' '{ print $3"/"$2"/"$1 }'
    }
```

Problem what i'm facing is perl script exit if cleartool command fails. I want perl to continue even though cleartool returns error.

BRs
Mani.

Comment: And what of `@Property` in the case where it fails?

Answer (score 8):

The simple and primitive way is to put the potentially failing code inside an eval block:

```
eval { @Property = `cleartool lsview -prop $viewtag ` };
```

That way your Perl script will continue even if cleartool fails.

The correct way is to use an appropriate module like [Try::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Try::Tiny). The error will be available inside the catch block in the variable $_.

```
try {
    @Property = `cleartool lsview -prop $viewtag `;
}
catch {
    warn "cleartool command failed with $_";
};
```

Comment: And for No/Low-CPAN sites, the "primitive" way is the way that is guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can try and use "[Try::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Try-Tiny-0.12/lib/Try/Tiny.pm)", as recommended in "[What is the best way to handle exceptions in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006267/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-exceptions-in-perl)".

The other approach is to use `eval` the cleartool command.

```
eval { @Property = `cleartool lsview -prop $viewtag` };
if ($@) {
    warn "Oh no! [$@]\n";
}
```