# Ruby error handling similar to Perl

Tags: ruby, perl, error-handling

In Perl I handle errors with:

```
eval{
     };
if($@) {
     }
```

In Ruby I have used:

```
 begin
 rescue Exception => e
 sleep 2
 end
```

Is this correct way to do in Ruby, and will this work if the Internet or a server goes down?
If the above is wrong are there any ways of doing it in Ruby similar to Perl?

Comment: Side note regarding perl `eval {};` http://stackoverflow.com/a/4006339/223226

Answer (score 2):

If you need to rescue from a possible exception, you got it right. You have to:

```
begin
  # do some useful but dangerious work
rescue StandardError => e
  # something went wrong, try to work around it;
  # object "e" containts usefull error information
ensure
  # anyway, cleanup after doing what you've started
end
```

P.S. If the server goes down literally (e.g. the hardware is off) – no exception code-handling will help you out.

P.P.S. The Internet probably won't go down anytime soon.