# global level exception handling in perl

Tags: perl, perl-module

I have written a perl program which internally calls three perl modules. My supervisor after reviewing the code asked me add global exception handling. I didn't understand what he meant by this. He also said use Eval to accomplish this.I am not sure how to use Eval so that it catches any exception in the enire perl module. Can anyone help me by providing links or by providing explanation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This might help: [What is the best way to handle exceptions in Perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006267/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-exceptions-in-perl)

Comment: I think you'll probably have to ask your supervisor! As far as I'm concerned, global exception handling in Perl involves writing a `die` handler by assigning a subroutine to `$SIG{__DIE__}` (as described in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables)). And it's something that's really only good for debugging. On the other hand, `eval` allows you to handle errors in only one block of the code. I guess if you had a `main()` subroutine that executed the whole program, like in C, then you could put that in an `eval { main(); }` block, but I'm not sure I see the point.

Comment: You got great advice and information from [Amadan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/240443/amadan) and [Borodin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin), whose comment also expresses the fact that it is not quite clear what your situation is; "global exception handling" is a strange term to me.  Here are a few questions:  How much/often do you call functions from those modules?  At what level -- buried deep inside subs or in `main::`?  What are the modules?  What is the size and structure of the whole project?  In a nutshell, I mean.

Comment: It's a pretty small project consisting of around 400 lines of code. What my supervisor needs is - totally I have 4 programs (one main program and three sub modules which are called from main). For each program he wants me to have an exception handling where in if something goes wrong it will be highlighted and it becomes easy for us to debug.

Comment: @nithin: But that already happens. If your code encounters a fatal error then it dies with a message giving the reason, as well as the source file and line number being executed at the time. Your supervisor has clearly flummoxed me and many other Stack Overflow subscribers, as you have had no answers so far at all. Are they asking for a stack backtrace? It may not be enough to know where in the code the failure occurred because the cause is ultimately due to wrong parameters being passed to a subroutine. Ask your supervisor for an *example* of an error and the information they would like

Answer (score 1):

> *For each program he wants me to have an exception handling where in if something goes wrong it will be highlighted and it becomes easy for us to debug.*

When an uncaught exception occurs, it is printed to STDERR. Your highlighting requirement is already being met.

Exceptions messages already include the line number at which they were thrown (unless specifically suppressed), so some information to help debug is already available.

```
$ perl -e'sub f { die "bar" } f("foo")'
bar at -e line 1.
```

Adding `use Carp::Always;` to your scripts will cause a stack backtrace to be provided as well, providing more information.

```
$ perl -e'use Carp::Always; sub f { die "bar" } f("foo")'
bar at -e line 1.
        main::f("foo") called at -e line 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are given seems imprecise.  "Global" and `eval` are somewhat contradictory, as 
[Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin) explained in his comment. Another way to do things "global" is given in [ikegami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/589924/ikegami)'s answer.  However, since mentioning `eval` *is*  specific here is a rundown on a very basic use of that.

You use `eval` on a block of code (or an expression but that is not what you want here). If a `die` is thrown anywhere inside that block, the `eval` catches that in the sense that you get the control back, the program won't just die. The variable `$@` gets filled with the error message. Then you can interrogate what happened, print out diagnostics, and possibly recover from the error.

```
eval {  run_some_code(@args) };
if ($@) {
    carp "Error in `run_some_code()`: $@ --";
    # Do further investigation, print, recover ...
}
```

You can have any code in the `eval` block above, it needn't be a single function call.  Note that `eval` itself returns values that convey what happened (aside from `$@` being set).

As for the "global" in your problem statement, one thing that comes to mind is that you use `eval` at the level of `main::` -- wrap in it any subs that themselves invoke functions from the modules.

A crucial thing about exceptions is that they "bubble up". When a `die` (Perl's sole exception) is thrown in a sub and the caller doesn't `eval` it, it goes up the call chain ... eventually showing up in `main::`, and if it is not caught (`eval`-ed) there *then* the program dies.  So you can `eval` the top-level call in `main::` and get to know whether anything anywhere below went wrong.

```
eval { top_level_call(); };
if ($@) {
    warn "Error from somewhere in `top_level_call(): $@";
}

# Functions
sub top_level_call {
    # doing some work ...
    another_sub();
    # doing more ...
}
sub another_sub {
    # do work, no eval checks
}
```

If an error triggering a `die` happens in `another_sub()` its processing stops immediately and the control is returned to the caller, the `top_level_call()`. Since that sub doesn't check (no `eval` there) its execution stops at that point as well, and the control returns to its caller (in this example the `main::` itself).  So it eventually hits `main::`, and `eval`-ing there lets you know about errors and your program won't just exit.

Perhaps that's what was meant by "global" exception handling using `eval`.

You can do far more along these lines, if this is what you need to be doing. See [eval](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html) for starters.
Update your question with clarifications, so you get more discussion here.

In practical terms, I would say that you equip yourself with some understanding of `eval` use as well as some of "global" error reporting, and then ask your supervisor for clarification and/or examples, as suggested by [Borodin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622310/borodin).